# How to install specific chromium version in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, chromium

I want to install Chromium 72.0.3626.121. What is the procedure?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux/build_instructions.md provides the procedure.

Install `depot_tools` by cloning the `depot_tools` repository:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

Add `depot_tools` to the end of your PATH (you will probably want to put this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`). Assuming you cloned `depot_tools` to *`/path/to/depot_tools`*:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"
```

When cloning `depot_tools` to your home directory do not use `~` on PATH, otherwise gclient runhooks will fail to run. Rather, you should use either $HOME or the absolute path:

```
export PATH="$PATH:${HOME}/depot_tools"
```

Get the code for [72.0.3626.121](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/72.0.3626.121) with

```
mkdir ~/chromium && cd ~/chromium && fetch --nohooks --no-history chromium
```

install additional build dependencies with

```
./build/install-build-deps.sh
```

run the hooks with

```
gclient runhooks
```

set up the build with

```
gn gen out/Default
```

paying attention to modifications for faster builds if you wish, then build Chromium with

```
autoninja -C out/Default chrome
```

Comment: not cleared,can you please provide commands to install Chromium 72.0.3626.121 so that i can execute directly because i am new in this.

Comment: What happens when you install the depot tools? When you got the code? Install the additional build dependencies? Ran the hooks? Set up the build? Built it? Please click [edit] and add the results for each step in your question.

Comment: fetch command takes too much time

Answer (score 0):

Just follow along

1. wget `https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+archive/72.0.3626.121.tar.gz`
   this is the source file that you want
2. Configure it after you go through the INSTALL / README - each source is very different. This will tell you how ready your system is with configuration, dependencies and libraries
3. If you get an error youre in luck - you know exactly the dep/lib missing. Get after figuring this dependency/library - start a new google search adn figure how to install it. One of the easiest configurations and installs from source is the CMAKE program - you will probably never fail in installing from source.
4. Once config is done - you only need to make. Make is a command so just use `make` - but `./makefile` should be used with an executable file. Id follow what the README says
5. You can use checkinstall if you want to manage your package with a package manager. I would.